# AS3: String to Function || Function to String

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a textField that displays some text, then when a timer goes off, the next piece of text is displayed, and so on. Alternatively, the user can press a key to make the next text appear instead of waiting for the timer.

```
var dispatchString:String;

function dispatchIt():void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event(dispatchString));
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,dispatchIt);


function text1():void {
    dispatchString = "text2";
    addEventListener("text2",text2);
    ...
    dispatchIt(); //when timer goes off

}
function text2(evt:Event):void {
    removeEventListener("text2",text2);
    dispatchString = "text3";
    addEventListener("text3",text3);
    ...
    dispatchIt();
}
```

I'm trying to simplify the part where I set the dispatchString and the addEventListener by instead calling a function with one parameter that does both. So something like:

```
function listenFor(s:String):void {
    dispatchString = s;
    addEventListener(s,this[s]);
}
```

But that won't work with nested functions. I was thinking there might be another way to pass the function instead and set the dispatchString to the name of that function, but I haven't had much luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the string of the event, why not set the event handler?

I would try the following:

```
var eventHandler:Function = text1;

function dispatchIt(evt:Event):void {
    callLater(eventHandler,[evt]);
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,dispatchIt);


function text1(evt:Event):void {
    eventHandler = text2;
    trace("text1");
    ...
    dispatchIt(evt); //when timer goes off

}
function text2(evt:Event):void {
    eventHandler = text3;
    trace("text2");
    ...
    dispatchIt(evt);
}

function text3(evt:Event):void {
    eventHandler = text1;
    trace("text3");
    ...
    dispatchIt(evt);
}
```

Comment: That would work, but it creates a huge call stack that doesn't pop until all the functions have been executed. In my actual program, there is a lot more stuff going on than just displaying text, and it is going to be quite long.

Comment: @BladePoint, then you can use callLater(). See fixed code above.